# Python 2.7.6. r.sub everything after an IP address in a log file

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to learn string manipulation in Python.  How can I tell Python to replace all text after the specific string is found.  For example, I have my Apache log file and I want to substitute everything that follows an IP address.

```
log_file = open('/home/Batman/Documents/python/scripts/accesslog')

for loop in log_file:
    relplacedText = re.sub(r'\d[1,3]\.\d[1,3]\.\d[1,3]\.\d[1,3]\s',r'Fire Ze Mizzles', log_file)
```

Thank you :)

Comment: Example input and expected output would sure be nice. In general, you want to include the IP you are looking for in the regex.

Answer (score 0):

Square brackets are for character classes like [a-zA-Z] means all upper/lower case letters. Curly braces are used to indicate length for matches. Here is a fiddle with some examples of real Apache log strings and the matches. If you click the "Python" button on the page you will be able to experiment with it.

[Regex fiddle](http://fiddle.re/a4rrm)

The following matches everything after the first IPv4 address. This actually matches the IP address and everything afterword in separate captures. You may not need to capture the IP address, but I guess you typically would. If you look at the fiddle you can see I did a sample replacement as well.

```
.*?(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})(.*)
```

Check the [Python re docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) for more info.

Comment: Yes. After I saw the post I realized that. Thank you though for your help. It seems like with regex I have the biggest problem when learning Python. It is tedious but I guess it is matter of practice :) Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the square brackets should be braces. Depending on what you actually want:

```
>>> x = "Fred 10.157.205.45, was here"
>>> print re.sub(r'\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}.*', r'Fire Ze Mizzles', x)
Fred Fire Ze Mizzles
>>> print re.sub(r'\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}(.*)', r'Fire Ze Mizzles\1', x)
Fred Fire Ze Mizzles, was here
```

Here the '.*' stands for any number of anything (to the end) and putting it in () saves it for later use by the '\1' construct. You can save the front and swap them around

```
>>> print re.sub(r'(.*[^0-9])\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}(.*)', r'\1Fire Ze Mizzles\2', x)
Fred Fire Ze Mizzles, was here
>>> print re.sub(r'(.*[^0-9])\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}(.*)', r'\2 Fire Ze Mizzles \1', x)
, was here Fire Ze Mizzles Fred
```

Comment: Thank you! I realized my mistake with the brackets. However what I don't I think I was going to be able to understand how to fix was the .*  I get it now. Thank you :)

Comment: Of course, you could accept one of the provided answers, which would make for one less _unanswered_ question.